# Trying to reach API using Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, .net-core, postman

I am building API restful server using dotnet core framework. I added my controller and trying to reach an endpoint using postman.

I have 2 problems

- #### Problem 1

  ```
  // POST api/user
  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize()]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserModel user)
  {
  }
  ```

Unless I send the request from postman as `application/json` by typing raw json, I can't reach this endpoint if I use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead I always get 415 unsupported media type

- #### Problem 2

  ```
  // POST api/user/avatar
  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize()]
  [Route("avatar")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserModel user, [FromBody]IFormFile file)
  {
  }
  ```

I don't know how to reach such an endpoint using postman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In problem 1 you just need to use FromForm attribute instead of FromBody.
As for second, i think will be easier write simple unit test or use [Swashbuckle](https://damienbod.com/2015/12/13/asp-net-5-mvc-6-api-documentation-using-swagger/), it has great interface for such requests

Comment: Thanks so much, but is there a way to accept both ```application/json``` and ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded```??

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Consumes` attribute like that:

```
// POST api/user
[HttpPost, Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
[Authorize()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserModel user)
{
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Still getting 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Me too, this is not helping unfortunately

Comment: for some reason, this worked for me. I was getting the 415 error in postman, and decided to give this a shot. upvoted.