# With Swashbuckle.AspNetCore how can i provide a form for FromBody parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

In my WebAPI, I have a change password method. It takes a parameter that is a class that contains two properties: "OldPassword" and "NewPassword".
Obviously, i do not want to pass that thru query strings, i want em passed into the body.
As soon as I use the FromBody attribute, the Swagger UI no longer offers a nice form with two textbox, it turns into a single JSON blob.

I'd like to mix those behaviors, provide a form but format the input into json that would match the schema.

I tried playing around with OperationFilters but couldn't achieve anything similar. 
I'm sure this is pretty common, but my google and stackoverflow searches haven't returned anything. Perhaps i'm not searching for the proper keywords. Unsure.

Comment: Does this help? - [Trying to reach API using Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42510382/113116)

Comment: Not quite. FromForm does give me the nice input boxes in swagger-ui, but then it produces requests that won't deserialize properly. I noticed it produces & separated key-value pairs, instead of json. Tried adding Consumes("application/json") without much success... tried with urlencoded and formdata too.

Comment: So If I understand correctly you want the from Url UI experience, but actually post in Body, right?  ... and no this is not pretty common

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yes, exactly. I wouldn't mind providing my code to format key-value pairs into well-formed json that will deserialize in the type of my parameter.
Since this is a change password, I can use Data annotations to specify it's a password and get nice little input boxes with hidden passwords. That's an elegant way to input. But i don't want clear-text password to travel in Query strings, since they can be logged along the way

Comment: How about `FromHeader` will that work for you?

Comment: Do you use Swagger UI 2.x or 3.x.? See [version detection](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md). 2.x has a JSON form editor, it can be enabled via a config parameter. 3.x does not currently have JSON form editor.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Thanks for the tip, i tried it. It doesn't work with my class directly, but copying my properties straight in the method did the trick. So it's good enough for me. :) 
Thanks!

Comment: @Helen I didn't know that, but yeah i'm using 3.19. I guess i'll just go with headers

Comment: Glad I could help, but Just like @Helen points out a single JSON blob is not the end of the world, and an editor can be added to ease the paint. it's just not available yet on the latest UI... the Swagger-UI should not be what your end users use to consume your api, Why was that such a pain point for you?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda That's a fair point. The services offered via this API will indeed be consumed by other ways, so in that case swagger is only useful for tests and documentation. BUT for some admin fonctions (like changing passwords), Swagger is the actual UI that will be used by support technicians. 
But still... i think you are right, i shouldn't design around swagger features/limitations. In that sense, i think i will back track and stick with JSON blobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided to stick with json blob in the body as it is the decison that makes the most sense, design wise.

I got it working with FromHeader, but considering that this is not the way this API should be consumed, we prefered to stick with designing for the actual use case and not around Swagger's features and limiations.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: 100% with you on that! Do NOT design around swagger features/limitations, if your support team want to use it learning JSON won't be the end of the world, you can also provide "fill the blanks" examples to make it easy to complete the required schema

Comment: And if you need a feature on the UI just request it: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues always check if there is a request already and leave a comment

Comment: Here's a feature request to add the JSON form editor in 3.x: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771