# Display all request-body parameters come as an individual input-box

Tags: swagger-ui, asp.net-core-5.0

Is there any way in a swagger to display all request-body parameters come as an individual input-box similar to the id field?

[image]

My action is setup as the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse<string>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCharge(int id, [FromBody] ChargeCreateRequestModel requestModel)
{

    return Ok(new ApiResponse<string>($"List of charge"));
}
```

Comment: Related: [With Swashbuckle.AspNetCore how can i provide a form for FromBody parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52821822/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Form-like editor is not available for JSON payloads. Here's the corresponding feature request:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771